# Possibility of using gluster volume in k8s if glusterfs client package on container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, glusterfs

Kubernetes supports several types of Volumes including GlusterFS. Also GlusterFS can be Persistent Volumes in k8s.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/examples/glusterfs/

For using glusterfs volumes in k8s, one of prerequisites is "Install Glusterfs client package on the Kubernetes nodes". But if it is expect that everything shall be in containers. Is that possible that put gluster client in container (e.g. DaemonSet deploy gluster client on k8s node first), while k8s still can suing glusterfs as above example?

Will k8s support such using scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is officially supported via the way you described at the moment, but take a look at this blog post, it outlines exactly what you describe: https://huaminchen.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/yet-another-containerized-mounter-for-kubernetes/

Comment: Appropriate for your help. Thank you.